# Can't install @microsoft/mgt via npm

Tags: node.js, git, npm, sharepointframework, microsoft-graph-toolkit

everyone,

when trying to install the package for the MS Graph toolkit via

`npm install @microsoft/mgt`

I receive an error that the typescript-typings package can not be found:

```
PS C:\Users\dev\Dev\Webpart> npm install @microsoft/mgt
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-typescript-typings.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\dev\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-03-11T11_44_15_649Z-debug.log
```

I tried several node versions via nodist. And also started a new project with the same results.
I use Windows 10 (1903).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+npm+ERR%21+enoent+spawn+git+ENOENT

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I do have git installed via git bash, but it was not set to my PATH. Never had this issue before when installing npm packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might not have git installed - You need to install git in your machine to have it working.

```
undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-typescript-typings.git
```

it should have been

```
git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-typescript-typings.git
```

There is error related to git path.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I do have git installed via git bash, but it was not set to my PATH.